# Hiding vertical scrollbar of multi-line SELECT in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: firefox, select, google-chrome, scrollbar

This problem seemed quite simple (`overflow:hidden`, right?) until I couldn't solve it. I have a simple multi-line SELECT with defined size:

```
<select size="10" name="elements">
... 
</select>
```

MSIE and Opera show vertical scrollbar only when needed, but Firefox and Chrome **always** display vertical scrollbar in disabled state.

I tried setting overflow, overflow-y, and even overflow-x, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, apparently: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=154496

Comment: seems like true, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
<select style="width: 110% ; border: 0px;">
.....
```

Comment: Explanation please (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

This is a rather old thread now but I imagine that there are others who run into it in quest of an answer to the very same question just as I did.  For Webkit browsers there is a very simple solution courtesy of the fact that they (Chrome and Safari) allow the scrollbar to be styled.

Here is a decent reference to many of the things you can do with [webkit scrollbars](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).  The CSS you need here is

```
select::-webkit-scrollbar{width:1px;background-color:transparent}
```

The trick is essentially doing two things

1. Make the scrollbar just one pixel wide so it doesn't get in the way
2. Set its background color to transprent

If you want this to work for only a subset of select scrollbars you should change the CSS by altering the scrollbar for a dummy class

```
.subsel::-webkit-scrollbar{width:1px;background-color:transparent}
```

and then use that class for the selects you want to thus modify.  e.g.

```
<select class='subsel' id='selOne' size='4'>
 <option value='1'>Option One</option>
 <option value='2'>Option Two</option>
</select>
```

Here is a fiddle that shows the "removed" scrollbar in action

[rememebr it will only work with Webkit browsers!](http://jsfiddle.net/xjRZb/)

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, `overflow: hidden` works fine.

In Firefox you can currently use `scrollbar-width: none;` to hide the scrollbar. This may one day [become a standard](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/#scrollbar-width), but as of 2020, only [implemented](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-width) by Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

You can, [using some JavaScript](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=283096#p1560260)

Not the best solution, but should work :)

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.border {
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-style:solid;
        overflow:hidden;
}
select.hiddenscroll {
    margin-right: -20px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    padding-right: -20px;
        overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
    <div class="border" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <select size="5" multiple="multiple" class="hiddenscroll" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless">
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
          <option>Option 4</option>
          <option>Option 5</option>  
        </select> 
    </div>
    <table>
    </tr></td>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A brief description of the solution to OP's problem would be better. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can think of is to overlap the scrollbar by positioning an image or solid `DIV` with a higher z-index right on top the `SELECT` scrollbar. But this would be an ugly hack.

Answer (score -1):

The solution from @mon breaks in some occasions (e.g. inside table cell), though it is a great solution. However this one is similar but better:

**[Hide vertical scrollbar in `<select>` element, solution with margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531269/hide-vertical-scrollbar-in-select-element#answer-11433927)**

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.